# Am I able to classify models with folders on django admin dashboard?

Tags: python, django, model, admin, dashboard

I'm fresh of the django boat, working on a project that need to do 'one to many'. Here's what I'm trying to make my admin dashboard look like:

- Patients

  - Patient001

    - Profile
    - Record
    - Inputoutput

      - Day1
      - Day2
  - Patient002

    - Profile
    - Record
    - Inputoutput

      - Day1

The "Patient", "Profile", "Record", "Inputoutput" are all models and related with a foreign key "name" in "Patient" model. I hope to achieve to add or edit the data in each model by clicking in folders on django admin dashboard. How should I do this. I've been googling for days. What I found that looks like I'm looking for is a "custom django admin dashboard", but still not sure how to do this. Anyone has an idea? =)

What I want to achieve is:

first>> create a "Patient" model (admin create a Patient Folder shows on dashboard)

then>> create a "Profile" model (click into the Patient Folder we just create and add a Profile model)

I want all these created models to show in levels of folders on admin, and you can just click in to the folders to add or edit instead of all of the registered models showing together on the very first page of admin.

Here are my models:

--patient.py--

```
from django.db import models

class Patient(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(default="", max_length=200)

def __str__(self):
    return self.name

class Meta:
    app_label = 'vsform'
```

--profile.py--

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
import datetime

class Profile(models.Model):
patient = models.ForeignKey('Patient', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
record_number = models.CharField(max_length=200)
bed_number = models.CharField(max_length=200)
gender = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=(('男', '男'), ('女', '女')))
operation_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
chart_start_time = models.IntegerField(default=4)

class Meta:
    app_label = 'vsform'

def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

--record.py--

```
from django.db import models

class Record(models.Model):
patient = models.ForeignKey('Patient', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

blood_pressure_day1_1 = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
blood_pressure_day1_2 = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
blood_pressure_day2_1 = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
blood_pressure_day2_2 = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
blood_pressure_day3_1 = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
blood_pressure_day3_2 = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
blood_pressure_day4_1 = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
blood_pressure_day4_2 = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
blood_pressure_day5_1 = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
blood_pressure_day5_2 = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
height_day1 = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
weight_day1 = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
height_day2 = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
weight_day2 = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
height_day3 = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
weight_day3 = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
height_day4 = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
weight_day4 = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
height_day5 = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
weight_day5 = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
special_drug1 = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
special_drug2 = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
special_drug3 = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
special_drug4 = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
exam1 = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
exam2 = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
exam3 = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
exam4 = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
exam5 = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
exam6 = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
exam7 = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
exam8 = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
exam9 = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
exam10 = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.patient.name

class Meta:
    app_label = 'vsform'
```

--inputoutput.py--

```
from django.db import models

class InputOutput(models.Model):
patient = models.ForeignKey('Patient', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

def __str__(self):
    return self.patient.name

class Meta:
    app_label = 'vsform'
```

--day.py--

```
from django.db import models


class Day(models.Model):
inputoutput = models.ForeignKey('InputOutput', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

day_number = models.SmallIntegerField(default=0)
injection_7to3 = models.IntegerField(default=0)
injection_3to11 = models.IntegerField(default=0)
injection_11to7 = models.IntegerField(default=0)
food_7to3 = models.IntegerField(default=0)
food_3to11 = models.IntegerField(default=0)
food_11to7 = models.IntegerField(default=0)
transfusion_7to3 = models.IntegerField(default=0)
transfusion_3to11 = models.IntegerField(default=0)
transfusion_11to7 = models.IntegerField(default=0)
excrete_times_7to3 = models.SmallIntegerField(default=0)
excrete_times_3to11 = models.SmallIntegerField(default=0)
excrete_times_11to7 = models.SmallIntegerField(default=0)
urine_7to3 = models.IntegerField(default=0)
urine_3to11 = models.IntegerField(default=0)
urine_11to7 = models.IntegerField(default=0)
vomit_7to3 = models.IntegerField(default=0)
vomit_3to11 = models.IntegerField(default=0)
vomit_11to7 = models.IntegerField(default=0)
drain_7to3 = models.IntegerField(default=0)
drain_3to11 = models.IntegerField(default=0)
drain_11to7 = models.IntegerField(default=0)

def __str__(self):
    return "Day " + str(self.day_number)

class Meta:
    app_label = 'vsform'
```

And here's admin.py

--admin.py--

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models.patient import Patient

admin.site.register(Patient)
```

Comment: I don't understand exactly. Could you add your models?

Comment: @seuling i've added my models, tell me if you need more! =)

Comment: OK now I see.. you want to add your admin model with two times for `Patient` model, right?

Comment: (Why would a patient's height vary over five days?)

Comment: Firstly, you don't need all those fields! Instead of 10 fields like `blood_pressure_day1_1`, BloodPressure should be a separate model with a ForeignKey field to Record and a `date` field. You could then look up Record.blood_pressure_set.all().order_by('date'). Same thing goes for height, weight, special_drug and exam

Comment: @seuling yes, but that's just the first step. I also want the admin to create a folder when adding a "Patient" that contain lower models (like: profile, record...)

Comment: @DanielRoseman 
Thanks for the advice. I know all these fields looks stupid LOL. I'm working on that too.

Comment: @ZG101
Thanks for the advice. I know all these fields looks stupid LOL. I'm working on that too.

Comment: What I want to achieve know is:
first>> create a "Patient" model (admin create a Patient Folder shows on dashboard)
then>>  create a "Profile" model  (click into the Patient Folder we just create and add a Profile model)

Comment: I want all these created models to show in levels of folders on admin, and you can just click in to the folders to add or edit instead of all of the registered models showing on the very first page of admin.